# How can redirect requests to my external IP address/port to a different external IP address/port in Linux without changing the source IP address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I can use the following commands, but they change the source IP address:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport port -j DNAT --to-destination dest_ip:port
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

So I get the source IP address at dest_ip's computer equivalent to this computer's IP address, but I want to get the real IP address.

If I remove `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`, I can't get any response. How can I solve this problem?

All IP addresses are external IP addresses.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `PREROUTING` rule without the `MASQUERADE` rule will do what you were asking for. It still won't work, but that is for a different reason.

If you have a client on `192.0.2.1` which send a SYN packet to your server on `198.51.100.2`, then your first rule can change the destination address of that packet to your other server on `203.0.113.3` and forward it as such.

The first problem you could run into with this approach would be that the connection between `198.51.100.2` and `203.0.113.3` might have source IP filtering. This would cause the packet to be dropped because the source address would still be `192.0.2.1` but the router expected `198.51.100.2`. If this is the case in your particular network, it can be worked around by using a tunnel.

However you will run into another problem. Once the packet arrives at `203.0.113.3` a SYN-ACK will be send back to `192.0.2.1`. This will be routed directly to the client without going through the first machine which had applied the `DNAT` rule.

The client which send a SYN from `192.0.2.1` to `198.51.100.2` will see a SYN-ACK from `203.0.113.3` to `192.0.2.1`. This will not match any TCP connection on the client, and the client will reply with a RST packet. Once the RST packet reaches `203.0.113.3` the TCP connection is closed on the server side.

In total four packets got transmitted, and the connection got closed on the server side before getting fully established. Those four packets will repeat as many times as the client retransmits the SYN until it times out.

There is a few ways to get around this problem:

- Route all traffic from `203.0.113.3` through `198.51.100.2` to ensure that it gets translated on the way back. Unfortunately this will make the public IP `203.0.113.3` useless for any other purposes.
- Assign a secondary IP to `203.0.113.3`, you could for example give it `10.0.113.3` as the secondary IP address. On `198.51.100.2` you `DNAT` to `10.0.113.3` and use a tunnel to `203.0.113.3` in order to get the packets to the proper destination host. On `203.0.113.3` you use a routing policy to ensure that packets with source IP `10.0.113.3` gets routed back through the tunnel, and other packets get routed over your default gateway.
- Stop using NAT and instead use a DSR load balancing approach to send packets from `198.51.100.2` to `203.0.113.3`. If those two are not directly connected with no router between them, this will again require a tunnel. But this time packets inside the tunnel preserve the original destination address, and `203.0.113.3` will not need a routing policy, instead it will send correct replies directly to the client. The drawback of this is that `203.0.113.3` will need to be assigned `198.51.100.2` as a secondary IP, and thus `198.51.100.2` and `203.0.113.3` will not be able to communicate with each other, but they will still communicate just fine with everybody else.
- If you only need to support HTTP, you can use a proxy instead of NAT. Then you can use `X-Forwarded-For` to let `203.0.113.3` know the original client IP. The web server on `203.0.113.3` will then need to trust `X-Forwarded-For` on any connections originating from `198.51.100.2` and ignore it on connections from other client IPs.